# Change WooCommerce Product Columns

Tags: woocommerce

Looking to have 3 column layout on https://sweetheartshair.com but can not override the 4 column layout

```
// Change number or products per row to 3
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
function loop_columns() {
    return 3; // 3 products per row
}
}
```

code sample is not doing anything - added this to the themes functions.php file as suggested in other samples.

Comment: Seems sorted on link shared.

Answer (score 0):

code sample above is correct -> I had it twice in functions file so was conflicting